# Having trouble linking to my Azure DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm publishing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app to Azure Websites. In my Azure portal, I linked the website to my Azure SQL database. However, when I click the "View Connection String" link on the portal, I get a popup that says there are no connection strings.

Please keep in mind that my connection string in my app have a different name i.e. it's not named DefaultConnection, rather it's named myAppNameConnection.

Also, I'm publishing the app directly from VS 2013 and I'm able to select the correct DB in the publish wizard. However, when the app is published it is NOT able to communicate with the database. Any idea what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your VS tool you have the right connection string configured in your Web.config file. 
When you publish the website in Azure, it overwrites automatically the connection strings in the web.config file with the ones stored as global variables in the website service.

You must go on the Azure portal, click on your website, then click on configure on the tab menu.
Go down to connection strings, and insert the right connection string there.